Write a member of a class in a csv file
I'm working on a project where I have a class called dog and I want the user to insert a new dog and then save it on a csv file.
public static void insert(){
        List<Dog> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
        String c;
        do {
            System.out.println("Insert new dog:");
            
            
            dogs.add(new Dog());

            System.out.print("Do you want to continue? (y/n): ");
            c = console.readLine();
            
        } while (c.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));


        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("macchine.txt"))) {
            for (Dog dog : dogs) {
                writer.write(macchina.toString());
                writer.newLine();
            }
     
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

How can I do it?

toString() has the sole purpose of producing output for human eyeball based debugging and nothing else. Make another method that produces a serializable string, and make a method for the reverse operation (turns one of those strings back into an instance). You will need to think about escaping and such.

I don’t see any image.

Modify your toString function like this:
public String toString(){
    return super.getproduttore() + ";" + this.getnome() + ";" + Integer.toString(this.getnumporte()) + ";" + Double.toString(super.getvmax()) +";" + Double.toString(super.getacc()) ;
}

and provide an header row like this:
String header = "Produttore;Modello;Numero di porte;Accelerazione(0-100 km/h);Velocità massima (km/h)";

write this row to .csv (change .txt with .csv) file before for loop
writer.write(header);
for (Macchina macchina : macch...


The “C” in CSV stands for comma not semicolon.

Generally best to use toString for dumping data when debugging, not for generating CSV.

Do not abuse toString
The toString method is meant to dump data while debugging.
Do not override that method for CSV.
CSV methods
Add methods for generating and parsing the CSV text.
record Vehicle ( String make , String Model , double acceleration , … ) 
{
    String toCsv()
    {
        return this.make + "," + … + "\n" ;
    }

    static Vehicle fromCsv ( String line ) { … return new Vehicle ( … ); }
}

CSV processing framework
CSV is not quite as simple as it seems.
First of all, what if your content contains the delimiter? Then you need to escape.
Secondly, there is a standard specification to respect, RFC 4180.
So the ideal solution is to leverage a CSV processing library rather than do it yourself. Fortunately you have a choice of several good libraries in the Java ecosystem. For example, Apache Commons CSV, and OpenCSV.
Search Stack Overflow to learn more. This topic has been addressed many times already.
